# How to get data out of Boost mutable_buffers_1?

Tags: c++11, boost-asio

I’m developing a system for our application to get data from an external device. As soon as I send it a specific message, it sends back short messages to us 10x/second (so about 1 message per 100 milliseconds). I’m using Boost for this communication.

The process is rather simple: I create the socket, send the message, giving it a handler for the message receive:

```
// Header file:
...
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> _theIOService;
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> _theSocket;
int size_of_the_data = 100;
std::vector<char> _raw_buffer = std::vector<char>(size_of_the_data);
boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1 _data_buffer = boost::asio::buffer(_raw_buffer, size_of_the_data);
...

// Implementation file:

...
void DeviceDataListener::initiateTransfer() {

    // create and connect the socket up here
    ...
    // send the message
    boost::system::error_code error;
    boost::asio::write(*_theSocket,
                        boost::asio::buffer(beginMessage),
                        boost::asio::transfer_all(), error);

    // start the receive
    auto handler = boost::bind(&SCUDataListener::dataHandler, this, _1, _2);
    _theSocket->async_receive( _data_buffer, handler );
    std::thread run_thread([&]{ _theIOService->run(); });
    ...
}

void DeviceDataListener::dataHandler (
    const boost::system::error_code& error, // Result of operation.
    std::size_t bytes_transferred           // Number of bytes received.
    ) {

    int foo = bytes_transferred;

    // this line crashes application
    char* pData = static_cast<char*>(_data_buffer.data());
}
```

It works, my handler gets called immediately, as it should. The problem is, I can’t get the data out of  `_data_buffer`. This:

```
auto it = _data_buffer.begin();
```

causes a crash, even though `_data_buffer` is valid. This:

```
const char* pData = static_cast<char*>(_data_buffer.data());
```

won’t compile. The error is “Method 'data' could not be resolved”. The `mutable_buffer_1` API says data() is a completely valid method that returns the beginning of the memory range.

Inspecting via a debugger, I can see that there is no error and I can see `data` as a member of `_data_buffer` and the memory address it contains does contain the data we’re expecting. The thing is, I can’t get to it via code. Does anyone know how to get to the data in a Boost `mutable_buffers_1`?

We’re using Eclipse CDT, C++11 and gcc running on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “Method 'data' could not be resolved”.

this error may be true, but it depends on what version of Boost you use. `data()` is member of `mutable_buffer` since >= 1.66 version. Because `mutable_buffer` is the base class for `mutable_buffers_1` your code should compile if you use at least 1.66 version of Boost.

If your version is < 1.66 you should use

```
 char* p1 = boost::asio::buffer_cast<char*>(_data_buffer);
```

to get the pointer to data in the buffer.

---

`_data_buffer.begin();`

you should not use `begin()` method, it returns pointer to `mutable_buffer_1` itself. This method is used by internal functions of asio-boost library, for instance to copy sequence of buffers, then `begin()` points the particular buffer to be copied.

Comment: That worked! Thanks, @rafix07! I sure wish the Boost libraries were documented better.

Comment: Glad, I could help :)